# Add record to MySQL always raises - "Input string was not in a correct format error"

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

Each time I am trying to add a record into DB a transaction fails with "Input string was not in a correct format error" even though I have tried with no strings involved !

The give you more insight into what I am trying to do, basically user of my application requests his session id on launch which keeps track of his activities, in the stage below, server has received a request and obtains a session id from MySQL, then it passes it back to client who uses this number to form an authentication to his own channel.

What I see from the log below appears to be some invalid conversion that raises this exception.

I am using:

1. .NET Core 2.1
2. Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 3.1.0
3. Oracle MySQL 5.1.73 compiled for linux-gnu x86_x64 (No chance to update it)

I hope someone can help.

Here is the troublesome code along with the definition of Entity, Table design and error log:

```
    public static uint CreateSession(UsageTracking usageTracking)
    {
        using (MySQL SQL = new MySQL())
        {
            SQL.UsageTracking.Add(usageTracking);
            SQL.SaveChanges();

            return usageTracking.SessionID;
        }
    }

   public class UsageTracking
    {
        [Key]
        public uint SessionID { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(7)] [Required]
        public string USID{ get; set; }
        [Required]
        public long Date { get; set; }
    }


class MySQL : DbContext
{
    public static string connectionHost;
    public static string connectionPort;
    public static string connectionDB;
    public static string connectionUsn;
    public static string connectionPsw;

    public DbSet<DB.UsageTracking> UsageTracking { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options
            .UseMySql($"server={connectionHost};port={connectionPort};database={connectionDB};user= 
                 {connectionUsn};password={connectionPsw}", mySQLOptions => mySQLOptions
                .ServerVersion(new Version(5,1,73), ServerType.MySql)
            );
    }
}
```

UsageTracking Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `UsageTracking` (
`SessionID` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
`USID` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
`Date` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`SessionID`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Error Log:

```
        <logevent time="2020-01-15 16:24:17.2857" level="ERROR">
          <message>Input string was not in a correct format.</message>
          <type>System.FormatException</type>
          <trace>   at System.Number.StringToNumber(ReadOnlySpan`1 str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer&amp; number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
           at System.Number.ParseUInt32(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
           at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToUInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
           at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringValueOption`1.ChangeType(Object objectValue) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.cs:line 703
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringValueOption`1.GetValue(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder builder) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.cs:line 674
           at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionSettings..ctor(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder csb) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ConnectionSettings.cs:line 39
           at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetPool(String connectionString) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ConnectionPool.cs:line 405
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 292
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 280
           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
           at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlRelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.BeginTransaction()
           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
           at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
           at ReportingServer.DB.CreateSession(UsageTracking usageTracking) in C:\Users\User\source\repos\Reporting Server\MySQL.cs:line 20
           at ReportingServer.APIs.GetSessionID() in C:\Users\User\source\repos\Reporting Server\APIs.cs:line 66
           at ReportingServer.APIs.Process() in C:\Users\User\source\repos\Reporting Server\APIs.cs:line 41
           at ReportingServer.HTTPServer.&lt;Listen&gt;b__10_0(Object HTTPRequest) in C:\Users\User\source\repos\Reporting Server\HTTPServer.cs:line 135</trace>
          <source>System.Private.CoreLib</source>
          <location>
          <ReportedIn>ReportingServer.Log</ReportedIn>
          <OnLine>17</OnLine>
        </location>
        </logevent>
```

Comment: seems that it happens when connection is opened. Please check the `connectionPort` value when `OnConfiguring` is executed

Comment: Can you post the values in the UsageTracking object?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you code below is working fine. Put a break point to check.

$"server={connectionHost};port={connectionPort};database={connectionDB};user= 
                 {connectionUsn};password={connectionPsw}"

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Answer by Oleksa was correct, I checked the Connection after the configuration and it was incorrect, Configuration part was incorrectly changed and I was just looking at the wrong part of code all the time...

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace reveals, that MySqlConnector cannot convert one of your supplied connection string options to a `UInt32`.

It is the `port` argument, in your case the `connectionPort` variable, that is not a valid `UInt32`. It needs to be a valid port number between `1` and `65535` (the default for MySQL is `3306`).

---

On a side note, Pomelo `3.1.0` does not officially [support](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql#supported-dbms-and-versions) MySQL `5.1.73`, so you might hit incompatibility issues in the future.